# Why can't I use julia addprocs?(ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: julia

I'm writing a program that should connect to remote virtual machines and then do distributed execution.

I have this warning:

```
"Warning: Identity file  /home/luigal/.ssh/id_rsa not accessible: No such file or directory.".(Even if the file exists and the path is correct)
```

The program crashes when I try to do :

```
worker=[("myuser@ip:port",1)]

addprocs(worker;sshflags="-i /home/luigal/.ssh/id_rsa",exename="/usr/local/bin/julia", tunnel=true,dir="/home/luigal/HGEpidemics-main/")
```

This is the project I am working on:
https://github.com/GalloLuigi/HGEpidemics-main

I need to do this work on:
https://github.com/GalloLuigi/HGEpidemics-main/blob/main/src/experiments/spreading/spreading_experiment_d.jl

https://github.com/GalloLuigi/HGEpidemics-main/blob/main/src/experiments/spreading_parallel/spreading_experiment_d.jl

Someone can help me?

The console says:

[terminal_pt1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItHoF.png)

[terminal_pt2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udTn9.png)

Comment: cross-post: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/why-cant-i-use-julia-addprocs-econnrefused/72477

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include errors and tracebacks as **text** rather than as screenshots?  On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content in posts, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.  For instructions on formatting your errors see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*.

Comment: Also, please make sure your question includes a [mcve] in the question itself, not just in your external github links.  From [ask]: *If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also copy the code into the question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.*  Questions are sometimes closed if they can't be understood without an external link.